# ScriptProperties & UserProperties had been deprecated

Tags: google-apps-script

The documentation for the [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) lists both, the [ScriptProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/script-properties) and [UserProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/user-properties) as:

> Deprecated. This class is deprecated and should not be used in new scripts.

... while the `DocumentProperties` seem to have no page in the documentation.

Q: is there any suitable replacement for these classes, in order to use them in new scripts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The replacement for the deprecated classes is the class [`Properties`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties).

`PropertiesService` has three methods `getDocumentProperties()`, `getScriptProperties()`, and `getUserProperties()`. Perhaps once upon a time these returned objects of those deprecated classes; but now they all return an object of class `Properties`.

Script properties, user properties, and document properties remain available and they are non-deprecated; it's just that the classes have been unified into Properties.

```
var sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
sp.setProperty("foo", "bar");
var up = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
up.setProperty("foo", "baz");
var dp = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
dp.setProperty("foo", "blargh");
Logger.log([sp.getProperty("foo"), up.getProperty("foo"), dp.getProperty("foo")]);
```

logs `[bar, baz, blargh]`.

Comment: after reading the documentation again, it indeed seems to be correct... it's not the `Properties` which where deprecated, but the direct access to them, without using `PropertiesService`.