# What is the best way to send out new versions of my Google Sheets tool when I'm storing user data in one of the sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Thanks to the amazing help I have received here on StackOverflow, my Calendar Analysis tool is nearly finished. I'm sure there will be bugs, tweaks, and lots of additions in the coming weeks so I'm wondering about the best way to make my updates available.

My plan right now is put new versions in a Shared Google Drive. Anyone at work using my tool will have to grab the latest Google Sheet, copy it to their local drive, and update the e-mail field (so I can retrieve their calendar data). The problem is, one of the sheets contains user entered values that need to be persistent.

I've researched the properties service, but that seems to be tied to each script. I've looked at libraries, but it seems complicated. Any suggestions? (I can, of course, just tell people to copy the values out of the old sheet and paste them in the new one, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.)

Comment: Look a little closer at PropertiesService.

Comment: Okay, will do. (By the way, I call you out in my comments, Cooper. You helped me figure out how to deduplicate an array when I first started working on this project.)

Comment: @Cooper I've been researching the PropertiesService some more and I'm still not sure how this would work, since the properties are attached to the script file, right? When someone makes a copy of my Google Sheet, and saves it to their Drive aren't they also making a NEW copy of the script file?

Comment: How about UserProperties?   `Gets a property store that only the current user can access, and only within this script.`

Comment: Would you mind giving more details about how you plan to do this? Have you tried using a Sheets add-on that essentially asks the users for their emails and then later retrieves their wanted data? @JohnCutter

Comment: @Cooper - I just looked up UserProperties and it says this feature is deprecated and shouldn't be used in scripts. Perhaps I could just save data to a new Google Sheet that users could keep in the same Google Drive folder?

ale13 - I am aware that you can create *private* add-ons but I haven't really looked into it. I'll do that. Thank you.

Comment: There still seems to be `PropertiesService.getUserProperties()`

Comment: I think that deprecation notice applies to a time in the past when they had three separate classes one for each user,document and script see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51690004/7215091)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for the task you have mentioned is in fact to use an add-on, more particularally a Sheets add-on.

If you do not want to deploy the add-on in the GSuite Marketplace, you can just make use of a private add-on:

> Private add-ons are only visible to users in the same domain as the add-on publishing account. They can't be installed by outside users. Private add-ons do not require add-on review. Private visibility is sometimes referred to as My Domain visibility.

In order to publish the add-on you should follow the steps in this documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons):

**Step 1:** Create a script version

**Step 2:** Configure the OAuth consent screen

**Step 3:** Enable the G Suite Marketplace SDK

**Step 4:** Configure the G Suite Marketplace SDK

With the following note:

> If you selected Private visibility for the add-on, the add-on should become available for use after a few minutes.

### Reference

- [Extending Google Sheets with Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/editors/sheets);
- [Building editor add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/building-editor-addons);
- [Publishing an editor add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons).